# Receiving image in Asynctask and display it in ImageView

Tags: android, tcp, android-asynctask, imageview

I'm trying receive the image over TCP (in Asynctask) and display it in ImageView but I have an error in onPostExecute. Anyone know why?

And also whether idea of receiving is correct, if the next step will be recurring receiving image over TCP and displaying it?

**Code:**

```
public class TcpClient extends Activity  {

ImageView imageView;

public static String aHost;
public String aSocketIn;

public static int aSocketInInt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bundle_result);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

        aHost = intent.getStringExtra("addressIp");
        aSocketIn = intent.getStringExtra("socketIn");

    aSocketInInt = Integer.parseInt(aSocketIn);


    new DownloadImageTask(aHost,aSocketInInt).execute();   
} }

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Bitmap > {

public Bitmap bitmap = null;
String Host;
int SocketIn;

public  DownloadImageTask(String Host,int SocketIn) {
        this.Host = Host;
        this.SocketIn = SocketIn;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

    ClientIn clientIn;

    try {
        InetAddress serwerAddress = InetAddress.getByName(Host);
        Socket socket = new Socket(serwerAddress, SocketIn);
        clientIn = new ClientIn(socket);
        bitmap = clientIn.Receive();
        return bitmap;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {    

    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);  // ERROR: Cannot resolve symbol 'imageView'
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `DownloadImageTask` class is not `inner-class` of `TcpClient` class which is extending Activity,so to access `imageView` object of ImageView in other class, need to send it on `DownloadImageTask` using class constructor in same way as doing currently for getting Host and `SocketIn` in `DownloadImageTask` class.

Change `DownloadImageTask` as for to using `imageView` "

```
public  DownloadImageTask(String Host,int SocketIn,ImageView imageView) {
        this.Host = Host;
        this.SocketIn = SocketIn;
        this.imageView=imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but whether idea of receiving is correct, if the next step will be recurring receiving image over TCP and displaying it?

Comment: @Se-BASS-tian: Yes correct, because image src data is received over TCP instead of ImageView in which want to display data which is received over TCP